# Add two matrices stored as list of list

Tags: python

I have two matrices each stored as a list of list and each storing numbers. How can I add the matrices together.

For example: I want

```
[[1,1], [1,1]] + [[1,1], [1,1]]
```

to be equal to

```
[[2,2], [2,2]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `numpy`, which is a very popular Python linear algebra library

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix([[1,1], [1,1]])
>>> b = np.matrix([[1,1], [1,1]])
>>> a + b
matrix([[2, 2],
        [2, 2]])
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `np.array`

Comment: @NilsWerner An array would work here too, but I meant what I wrote :)

Comment: I still suggest to change it, as [SciPy itself suggests to use `array` over `matrix` if you don't specifically require a feature found in `matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension

```
a = [[1,1], [1,1]]
b = [[1,1], [1,1]]
c = [[a[i][j] + b[i][j] for j in range(len(a[0])) ] for i in range(len(a))]
```